# with webpack, why should one import CSS files from JS source code and not build CSS in isolation like the tradition did?

Tags: css, webpack

webpack doc for loading css:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css1

The webpack doc asks to import the CSS files from the Javascript code and to then run extract-text-webpack-plugin to extract the CSS.

--> with webpack, why should one import CSS files from JS source code and not build CSS in isolation like the tradition did?

By not importing CSS from Javascript, I mean that the webpack config for CSS has no ".js" extension, and it parses the CSS/SCSS files directly.

There are benefits of not importing CSS from javascript:

1. (objective fact). If one wants to build only CSS, it will be faster if the bundler does not need to parse the Javascript source code. Besides, one can run the bundlers for CSS and Javscript in parallel by using parallel-webpack.
2. (subjective, based on tradition, but most important in my opinion). SASS building in isolation has been the tradition for years. Therefore, we can achieve better HTML semantics and maintainability. Importing CSS from JS is virtual and may lead to neglect the generated separate CSS bundle.
3. (objective fact) One can split more the config files for CSS and Javascript, for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I'm more a traditionalist than most as i've been doing this for over 15 years, but I would say the *new* way to separate concerns is better than the traditional way.

In the old thinking we use to separate layout from styling from functionality (html from css from js).  This is more 'vertical' and made knowing where files are easy, but made finding specific code to do with 'features' hard.  I.e. a button might be made up of a small button section within `/src/shop-front.html`, a few lines of code within `/src/css/shop-front.css` and then the enhanced functionality would live somewhere in `/src/js/shop-front.js`

The new way of thinking is to separate concerns by components. So now you would have your shop-front, but this would be made from `/src/components/button/` and all files will live in the same place.  Including the js file which includes the css as mentioned.

The benefit being, if you decide to swap `button` for `fancy-button` all you do is change the shop-front `import button from 'button'` to `import button from 'fancy-button'`.  all old code will be removed automatically. no need to try to digest and change code in multiple places.

To address your concerns:

1. true, node-sass is fast, but I would say the difference between that and going via webpack is negligible and the improvement in dev experience (as mentioned above) is worth any extra ms
2. This point does apply as the way the css/sass is built does not change just because we require it from a js file.   I guess you mean if you were to use css modules, but this is a choice, you don't have to.  I use sass and apply class names as i would normally.
3. In webpack config, you could split the js config from the css config if you wanted to.  I wouldn't argue that this would make things any clearer though.  the config is so small, it's not worth worrying about.

My folder structure is nice and easy to reason with:

[image]

This is a basic config for simple scss imports

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const { SRC, DIST } = require('./src/config/paths');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  cache: true,
  context: SRC,
  entry: {
    app: [`${SRC}/client-entry.js`]
  },
  output: {
    path: DIST,
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]-[contenthash].css'),
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', SRC],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [/src/],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        include: [/src/],
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Interesting. 1. "a few extra ms"? JS only: 5.012s, SCSS only: 1.448s, JS + SCSS in parallel 0m5.420s. Only by using parallel webpack, 1.0s is won. It is not accurate due to startup time. I did not measure CSS import from Javascript but the combined parsing has a cost. 2. I meant that since the final CSS bundle is separated, the mapping JS to CSS is virtual and may lead to forget to worry about the generated CSS (you may forget to use a placeholder extend if you only look at isolated components). 3. Without parallel-webpack, you cannot deactivate source-maps for JS, and activate them for CSS.

Comment: ok, maybe a 'few ms' was an over exaggeration when comparing css only with js + css. most people now compile jsx + scss so i feel it won't be that far out when comparing like for like. But, the point being is that the dev experience and maintenance is much improved and any extra compile time is worth it.

Comment: 2) i see, as you say, the mapping is virtual, but the dev experience is very real and improved.  Code can still be shared globally as with normal scss.  If button.scss needs a mixin import it.  This is much easier to read than in the old days when you 'assumed' all mixins were already imported, probably in a central 'app.scss'.  Now you can see exactly what files button needs, and where things are, as it is declared at the top.

3) feels like nit picking here as i've never wanted one without the other. having both isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Interesting to know why you prefer the other way. a) That the unused code is removed automatically does not seem very useful. The unused CSS code would still be there polluting your folders. b) In summary, importing CSS from JS simplifies to have files located in folder for components. Stack Overflow is about facts. If it is good or not to locate files here or there belongs to preference and opinion. But there is another fact, related to which editor and way of working one uses. One can add symbolic links in the folders. I don't open files with the mouse. I use the keyboard or the shell.

Comment: so obviously you should remove unused code also, and this becomes easier when 'compontised'.  I've witnessed others, at all levels and multiple companies, not tidy up css after removing components for fear of what else would be affected.  I've seen these same people much more confident with 'componentised' code.   i'd always tidy up, not matter the structure, but i'm experienced.  This is getting a bit subjective/side-tracked now and i'm not sure you'll get any different answers.

Comment: OK :o) Thanks for the comments. I think it is very interesting for people to know that there are different ways. I really learnt a lot myself on Stack Overflow on many subjects. And you are right prefering one way or another makes the subject subjective.

Comment: I gave at the link below the reason why SASS can be well structured (not better) in the traditional way, based on 2 books I have read: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/webpack-what-do-you-think-of-this-way-building-css-and-javascript-separately/284349/12